# Is it okay to regularly turn off lamps (2) via a power strip rather than their individual switches?

Tags: electrical, lighting, safety, cord-and-plug, extension-cord

Okay, full disclosure: I know next to nothing about electronics. Just trying out my first little amateur diy project: adding lights to my vanity. So here goes my question.

I just bought 2 little clip-on "ETL-listed" lamps to clamp onto the top of my vanity, but they have rotary switches instead of in-line cord switches so it will be hard to reach up to turn them off easily. I'll need a longer cord for one of them anyway, so I was thinking to kill two birds with one stone and get a power strip/surge protector to use as an on/off switch as well instead of turning off their individual switches. My question: Would that be a bad idea??

Because I know you're not supposed to do that with computers, but I don't know if that applies to lamps too. I'm mainly worried about starting an electrical fire, not so much the cheap lamps. The 2 lamps take only one 60-watt bulb each if that's important (planning to use the SORAA A19 11-watt-usage, 60-watt-equivalent LED bulbs).

Oh and side note, it's a wooden (expensive) vanity- is it still okay to attach lamps if that's the case?? The lamps have rubber-coated clamps, and I'm using LED lights, but I'm slightly worried about it turning into a fire hazard.
  I have a 30-day return policy on these lamps. Any info/advice is appreciated!! Thanks!!!!

Update 1 (to address questions in comments): It's a bedroom vanity.

Update 2 (to address questions in comments): in TX, USA.

Comment: You mention this is a vanity, which immediately makes me think of a bathroom setting.  Is this the case here?  If so, we have to consider the interaction between a surge protector and a GFCI (surge protectors may have a capacitor that will cause the GFCI to trip).  You can get a power strip without a surge protector, and if you do not have a GFCI outlet at your sink, you will want a GFCI power strip for safety.

Comment: The GFCI protection needs to occur at the receptacle or prior to the receptacle.  Having a GFCI breaker or deadfront feeding a plain receptacle is fine, I would not waste money on a GFCI power strip.

Comment: @Harper All of this about GFCI is moot if this is a dressing room vanity and not a bathroom vanity.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I think *ETL* suggests Canada.

Comment: @bib -- Intertek ETL could be US or Canada, although I'm trying to get an answer from the OP here as there seems to be confusion on the part of some commentors here

Comment: @Keeta It's actually a bedroom vanity.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel In TX, USA.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In most cases, simple switches are equivalent. They break the circuit and do nothing else. So switching (breaking the circuit) further down the line is usually fine.

There are some exceptions, such as dimmers, multi-position switches, and multi-pole switches, none of which seem in play here.

The computer is different because it need to be shut down (program exited) rather than simply turned off. And some computers never really turn off but keep a very low power program running to allow fast start or remote update or activation.

The use of LED bulbs in a socket that is properly rated for incandescent bulbs will likely not generate any dangerous heat when properly mounted. ETL seems to be similar to UL safety listing. You do need to check if the mounting instructions specify minimum clearances.

The only risk you may face is possible damage to the finish of the vanity after long term grip by the rubber coated clamps. Some rubbers and plastics break down or give off solvents over time.

Comment: To expand on why computers should not be unplugged: Files being written to become corrupted, and hard-disk drives perform an emergency shutdown procedure which shortens their lifespan through mechanical stress.

Comment: @Fax This only explains why computers should not be unplugged **suddenly**. It's perfectly fine to unplug a computer after proper shutdown, eg to prevent power-on due to update or remote activation.

Comment: modern computer operating systems lose little or no data on power failure, because the apps are designed to keep a "running update" on temp copies.  You'll get some nasty notes when booting up about "this computer did not shut down correctly..."  but will be able to recover most stuff.

Comment: This answer is technologically correct on the EE side (how the electrons flow).  However it seems to me the crux of OP's question relates to Code/safety, and this answer does not seem to address that.  e.g. whether it is legal/safe to use flexible cords in place of conventional building wiring.

Comment: @Harper The code does allow extension cords and power strips. The OP appears to be using approved portable lamps that are rated for clamp on use. While serial extension cords, or use of non portable (or *no extension allowed*) devices on flexible cords are not proper, the proposed use does not seem to be excessive or dangerous.

Comment: That seems like an oversimplification.  We just had a question yesterday on where flexible cords are, or are not, allowed.  There's quite a list.  400.7 and 400.8 and vicinity, if I recall.  I see where the cords from the luminaires would be OK. However, from their plugs to the building's permanent wiring is what I would want to have someone look at closely.

Comment: @Harper You reference NEC 400 paragraphs...  Did I miss where OP stated they are in a NEC area?  ETL SEMCO has certification offices on 6 continents.  Soraa Lighting is in the US, UK and Japan.  Seems to me that the NEC paragraphs you mention are from code used mainly USA and even then it is not adopted in Arizona, Missouri and Mississippi.  So, do we assume those standards?

Comment: Well put it this way, if you are claiming your advice is good because NEC is inapplicable, then the burden is on you to show first that NEC is inapplicable and second that whatever code *is* applicable doesn't have the exact same rule.  It's like arguing that burglary is OK in France because US anti-burglarly laws don't apply there.  That's a bold claim, and requires bold proofs.

Comment: @Fax can you link evidence of this? I am under the impression that if a HDD loses power, the airflow from the spinning disk & lack of power for the electromagnet causes it to 'home' itself automatically. There is a special flap of plastic that catches the airflow & I've seen it in every single drive, even 10+year old ones.

Comment: @RozzA There are several ways to park the head during power loss. This was the particular one I was thinking of: "In the event of power loss to the drive, HGST invented a fault-tolerant retract system to move the heads to the park
position by extracting energy generated from the spinning disks through a high-efficiency retract circuit." https://www.hgst.com/sites/default/files/resources/LoadUnload_white_paper_FINAL.pdf

Comment: Great, looks like I don't have to return the lamps then. What does it mean to check minimum clearances though?

Comment: Some devices warn that they should not be placed closer than x inches from walls or other surfaces. Many do not have such warnings, but common sense says not to place incandescent lamps close to surfaces that could be damaged by heat. If there is no warning, the clamps themselves should be OK on furniture.

Comment: @bib Does that apply to LED bulbs too? The vanity is only a couple inches from the wall.

Comment: @Keeta I'm confused- I've never heard of NEC before. I googled it, but I'm not sure what it means for my project.

Comment: Most LED bulbs give of very little heat. In fact, the base of the bulb is usually warmer than the lit area. Test the bulb. Leave it on for ten or more minutes and then move your hand towards the lit area and the base. If it is not too hot to touch, it should pose no heat risk.

Comment: @Arya28 NEC is National Electrical Code (officially known as NFPA 70 - National FIre Protection Association).  It's a set of rules for electrical items.  They are adopted as official rules for the state of Texas.  The answer here covers most (if not all) of what you need to consider.  There would be more considerations if this had been in a "wet" setting, such as a bathroom or kitchen.